# R shiny - how to fill out the entire space of the browser window with an iframe

Tags: r, iframe, shiny

How can I fill out the entire length of the browser window? While `width="100%"` seems to work fine `height="100%"` seems to fill out a frame which is invisible to me.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fillPage(
    htmlOutput("frame")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$frame <- renderUI({
    tags$iframe(src="https://stackoverflow.com/", height="100%", width="100%")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can adapt the height of the iframe with the `style` argument. For some reaseon setting it to `height:100%` does not work, but setting it to  `height:100vh` does (viewport height)

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fillPage(
  htmlOutput("frame")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$frame <- renderUI({
    tags$iframe(src="https://stackoverflow.com/", style='width:100vw;height:100vh;')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```